# Post params not able to grab from postman + node js

Tags: node.js, rest, express, postman

I have the following code in my routes file:

```
router.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    console.log(email);
});
```

I am making a post call from postman with following details:
http://localhost:3000/login/submit

params:

```
email=abcxyz@gmail.com
```

and headers i have tried both

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

and

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Also, I have body parser separately installed with following in app.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

But, The console log for email shows 'undefined'. Why am i not able to grab the post params with req.body.email.

Comment: In body option what do you choose? form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded, raw or binary?

Comment: R u able to hit your api with this call  http://localhost:3000/login/submit ?

Comment: You are creating a post route for '/submit' in node app and trying to hit http://localhost:3000/login/submit using postman. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

In my case

[http://127.0.0.1:3000/submit](http://localhost:3000/lsubmit)

```
router.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
console.log("Your Email is "+req.body.email);
res.end(); // if you not end the response it will hanging...
```

[image]

**set your header type only**

```
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

[image]

**Body**

[image]
Console output
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I faced the similar issue and got it working, please follow the below steps

1. In Headers tab put content type as below

> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

2. In Body tab select ***x-www-form-urlencoded*** checkbox and put params.

> email=abcxyz@gmail.com

Now in your node app use below code

```js
router.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    console.log(email);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    [let express = require('express');
    let app = express();

    // For POST-Support
    let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    let multer = require('multer');
    let upload = multer();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.post('/api/sayHello', upload.array(), (request, response) => {
        let a = request.body.a;
        let b = request.body.b;


        let c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
        response.send('Result : '+c);
        console.log('Result : '+c);
    });

    app.listen(3000);

Please see the below example in the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955103/cant-get-post-data-using-nodejs-expressjs-and-postman/53514520#53514520

This will help you][1]
```

[Set Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp8Gp.png)

[Set Content-type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/633Fv.png)

Comment: Ok sure. I will add the answer. Thanks

Comment: Now it is fine?